# mysqli database conenction works sometimes

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm trying to make a web interface for a server in a game. I'm trying to get the website to read from the database. for this i'm using:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("some.host", "user", "password", "databasename");
```

The database is not hosted at a different hosting company than the one the website is hosted on.

95% of the time it works perfectly. However, sometimes it does not manage to connect to the database and gives the error:`Name or Service not known`
Note that i did not change anything, just refreshed page.
Database is still accessible from phpMyAdmin, and also in-game (the in-game server is hosted at the same site as the database).

I guess i'm asking what is the problem here. Is it the database host or the website host that's having problems? or something different?

Comment: As another user has already pointed out, this is not a MySQL problem. It’s a connection or, more likely, a routing error. Your host is probably not configured correctly.

Comment: Host is configured correctly, its set up automatically. There's nothing i can change to the database setup. Only thing i can think of is sending a message to the database host asking if they're having unreliability in their databases

Comment: I’m talking about the web or database host, specifically their DNS and routing. Search for this error, and you’ll see it’s something you need to resolve with your hosting provider.

Comment: Ill try to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a connection problem. Furthermore, it seems like the connection error is coming from the client side (your website) rather than the database.

You should doublecheck that your host is set up properly and that the connection of the hosting provider is reliable.